# scala.MatchError: java.lang.StackOverflowError (of class java.lang.StackOverflowError)

Tags: scala, playframework, stack-overflow

I had a project that was developed using play scala 2.0 and it was working fine and i had a need to upgrade the version to 2.3.8 . So i migrated my application version by following this link https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23
and i am able to run the code in newer version in my machine where i have 8 GB RAM and jdk 1.7.0_25 but when i run the code from some other machines with 4 GB RAM it throws the following error 
[image]

Even it is breaking in some systems with 8 GB and jdk 1.8 i am getting confused whether the issue is due to jdk or memory or an issue in play 2.3.8 
Can somebody help me in getting this issue resolved

Attached link to my complete [stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/A0yBTiaJ)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please copy the stack trace as text instead of posting a screenshot?

Comment: @ChrisMartin updated my question with link to stacktrace

Comment: Can you check the application.conf file - maxConnectionsPerPartition= ?,         minConnectionsPerPartition= ? .

Comment: @Karthik, clear the workspace and  rebuild your application. This might solve the issue.

Comment: @Altius no i havent specified maxConnectionsPerPartition and  minConnectionsPerPartition in my application.conf file

Comment: @S.K this is not happening on eclipse also tried cleaning the project but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @Karthik, this might be problem with configuration files, are you compiling from eclipse IDE or console ?

Comment: @S.K I am trying from the console

Comment: can you try `activator -Xmx1024M-XX:MaxPermSize=512m run`

Comment: @S.K that doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73839/discussion-between-karthik-and-s-k).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's a stackoverflow exception, bumping up the stack size did the trick for me:

```
export SBT_OPTS=-Xss4m
```

You can try adjusting the number to see what works.  I'm still not clear on the root cause as it repros on both Java 7 and Java 8, and have seen the error pop up at compile time as well.

Comment: Where should be this in Windows..?

Comment: It's just an environment variable.  Instructins are here http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: i am adding "SBT_OPTS=-Xss8m" in my build .sbt file but its giving me error "/home/smat/scalaworkspace/myproject/build.sbt:9: error: not found: value SBT_OPTS
SBT_OPTS=-Xss8m", how can i resolve it please guid me

Comment: That setting is for the JVM, it's not an SBT setting. So you need to have it passed to the JVM when it launches SBT.  SBT_OPTS is just an environment variable that is passed to the JVM when it launches SBT.

Answer (score 3):

Encountered the same problem after searching for long on this issue.
Try starting your application with this command

"activator clean -Xms1g -Xmx2g run"

if it doesn't work try increasing 1g and 2g to 2g and 3g resp.

Edit:
If, you want to avoid specifying parameters every time you run the application. you can add this into `build.sbt` file as follows:

```
javaOptions ++= Seq(-Xms1G, "-Xmx2G")
```

Comment: is there any way to hard code this? instead of each time typing it?

Comment: @behzad Edited my answer you can check it there.