# Unexpected exception in Play with Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am having an **Unexpected exception** in my Play2 application with Scala. The same error as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250004/scala-matcherror-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-of-class-java-lang-stackoverflow/29269492#comment49250965_29269492) question

This is what I get in a browser:

> scala.MatchError: java.lang.StackOverflowError (of class
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError)
>        play.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
>        play.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
>        scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
>        play.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44)
>        play.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40)
>        play.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
>        play.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
>        scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:377)
>        play.PlayReload$.compile(PlayReload.scala:17)

My stack traces are very large. A part of them looks as follows:

> scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5332)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5279)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5283)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$93.apply(Typers.scala:4440)
>   [error] (compile:compile) java.lang.StackOverflowError [error]
>   application -
>
> ! Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
>
> scala.MatchError: java.lang.StackOverflowError (of class
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError)     at
>   play.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   play.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
>   ~[na:na]  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
>   ~[scala-library-2.11.5.jar:na]    at
>   play.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]     at
>   play.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40) ~[na:na]

I have tried the answers to change the heap and stack size but when I run jconsole it showed that it did not work.

I also tried to change its heap size from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372468/sbt-specify-java-heap-size-in-build-scala/27373101#comment43198372_27373101) link but it also did not work and I am still  getting the same error.

Here is my build.sbt file :

```
 name := """myproject"""

    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

    scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

    fork in run := true

    javaOptions in run ++= Seq(
        "-Xms1G", "-Xmx2G", "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M", "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC")

    //SBT_OPTS=-Xss8m

    //JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m "

    //val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq( javaOptions += "-Xms1G -Xmx2G"
    //)

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test"withSources() withJavadoc(),
                        "com.esotericsoftware.kryo" % "kryo" % "2.10",
                    "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.8.0",
                    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.6.4",
                    "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.5.0",
                    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test"withSources() withJavadoc(),
                    "org.easymock" % "easymock" % "3.1" withSources() withJavadoc(),
                    "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5",
                    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.6",
                    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % "1.0.9",
                    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.9"
                    )
```

Please guide me.

Comment: add the exact error and stacktrace..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the stack size worked for me

I used this command to run the project

> activator run  -J-Xss4M -server